# How to access this variable from inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm learning Java and I came across inner class. I'm wondering how to access the variable 'temp' present in the outer class from the inner class.

```
class Demo
{
    private String temp = "Hello!";
    class Demo2
    {
        private String temp = "Hello22!!";
        public void show()
        {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}

class HelloWorld 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Demo d = new Demo();
        Demo.Demo2 d2 = d.new Demo2();
        d2.show();
    }
}
```

Here, we used the same variable name in both inner and outer classes. Is this considered as overloading?

Comment: It is called *shadowing*